# Plot stacked (100%) bar chart for multiple categories on multiple dates

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouping

I have following initial dataframe:

|  | Post ID | Submission_Date | Flair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | row1 | 01.12.2020 | NaN |
| 1 | row2 | 03.12.2020 | Discussion |
| 2 | row3 | 03.12.2020 | News |
| 3 | row4 | 03.12.2020 | Discussion |
| 4 | row5 | 06.12.2020 | Due Diligence |
| 5 | row6 | 07.12.2020 | Discussion |
| 6 | row7 | 31.12.2020 | Discussion |
| 1 | row8 | 01.01.2021 | Hedge Fund Tears |

- Multiple Dates with missing dates in between
- Multiple categories on dates

I grouped the dataframe with:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for test data

data = {'Post ID': ['row1', 'row2', 'row3', 'row4', 'row5', 'row6', 'row7', 'row8'], 'Submission_Date': ['01.12.2020', '03.12.2020', '03.12.2020', '03.12.2020', '06.12.2020', '07.12.2020', '31.12.2020', '01.01.2021'], 'Flair': [np.nan, 'Discussion', 'News', 'Discussion', 'Due Diligence', 'Discussion', 'Discussion', 'Hedge Fund Tears']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Submission_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Submission_Date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 

df = df.groupby('Submission_Date')['Flair'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack()
```

The result is this:

[image]

I want to fill the dates with "empty" bars and plot like this

[something like this](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/100-clustered-column-chart-in-Power-BI/td-p/464591):

I tried already this:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,10))
df.plot(kind='bar',ax=ax, stacked=True, width=1)
plt.xlabel('Submission_Date', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Ratio of Flairs used', fontsize=16)
```

But the dates are incorrect since the empty days are not displayed

[image: this graph]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this input as `df2` (the output of your `groupby` operation):

```
Flair            Discussion  Due Diligence  Hedge Fund Tears      News
Submission_Date                                                       
01.01.2021              NaN            NaN               1.0       NaN
03.12.2020         0.666667            NaN               NaN  0.333333
06.12.2020              NaN            1.0               NaN       NaN
07.12.2020         1.000000            NaN               NaN       NaN
31.12.2020         1.000000            NaN               NaN       NaN
```

You can `reindex` from `pd.date_range`:

```
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index, format='%d.%m.%Y')
df2 = df2.reindex(pd.date_range(df2.index.min(), df2.index.max()))
df2.index = df2.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
Flair       Discussion  Due Diligence  Hedge Fund Tears      News
2020-12-03    0.666667            NaN               NaN  0.333333
2020-12-04         NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN
2020-12-05         NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN
2020-12-06         NaN            1.0               NaN       NaN
2020-12-07    1.000000            NaN               NaN       NaN
...
2020-12-30         NaN            NaN               NaN       NaN
2020-12-31    1.000000            NaN               NaN       NaN
2021-01-01         NaN            NaN               1.0       NaN
```

graphical outcome (small size):

[image: missing dates]