# Convert dataframe for category percentages in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i would like to convert a dataframe with calculating percentage points for a graph later on in python.

The current frame looks like this

| Post ID | Title | Url | Author | Score | Submission_Date | Total_Num_of_Comments | Permalink | Flair | Selftext | TitleAndText | Word Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| k4nllk | Update: Whassup bro? | https://www.reddit.com/r/GME/comments/k4nllk/update_whassup_bro/ | matt_xndever | 1 | 2021-01-01 16:58:48 | 13 | /r/GME/comments/k4nllk/update_whassup_bro/ | Hedge Fund Tears | asdasdasd | asdasdasdasd | 59.0 |

Where flairs are the categories i want to look for (over 40). On one submission day (i want to look onto days only), there can be multiple posts with different flairs. These flairs should add up to 100%.

So i want to create a dataframe like that:

| Submission_Date | Discussion | Due Diligence | Hedge Fund Tears | News |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | NaN | NaN | 1.0 | NaN |
| 03.01.2021 | NaN | 0.333333 | 0.666667 | NaN |

My graph should look like this:
[Plot stacked (100%) bar chart for multiple categories on multiple dates in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671752/plot-stacked-100-bar-chart-for-multiple-categories-on-multiple-dates-in-pytho/68689289#68689289)

Can someone help me with the preparation for that?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approach the problem as follows:

- iterate over unique dates and slice the dataframe for each date
- compute counts for each flair category with pandas `value_counts()`
- get shares by dividing over the size of each slice
- transpose the pandas series containing the shares for appending
- append the shares for each date

Here is a sample input:

```
df = {
    'Submission_Date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-03-01', '2021-04-01', '2021-04-01'],
    'Flair': ['Hedge Fund Tears', 'Hedge Fund Tears', 'Hedge Fund Tears', 'Due Diligence', 'Discussion', 'News']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['Submission_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Submission_Date'])
display(df)
```

[image]

And here is a sample implementation:

```
unique_flairs = list(df['Flair'].unique())
flair_df = pd.DataFrame()

# iterate over unique dates
for date in df['Submission_Date'].unique():
    date_subset = df.loc[df['Submission_Date'] == date]
    # for flairs in each date, get counts of values
    counts = date_subset['Flair'].value_counts()
    # get shares
    shares = counts / len(date_subset)
    # transpose series for appending
    shares_df = pd.DataFrame(shares).transpose()
    shares_df['Submission_Date'] = date
    for flair in [x for x in unique_flairs if x not in shares_df.columns]:
        shares_df[flair] = np.nan
    # append shares per date
    flair_df = pd.concat([flair_df, shares_df])
    flair_df = flair_df.reset_index(drop=True)

# rearrange columns
flair_df = flair_df[['Submission_Date'] + unique_flairs]
display(flair_df)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot table to achieve this result. I made up the input data frame with some random values.

```
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict({
    "Submission_Date": [
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 2),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 2),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 3),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 3),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 3),
        datetime.date(2021, 1, 4),
    ],
    "Flair": ["Discussion", "Due Diligence", "Due Diligence", "Discussion", "Discussion",  "Hedge Fund Tears", "News", "News"],
})
data["Flair1"] = data.Flair.values # copy to another column to assist pivot
res = pandas.pivot_table(
    data,
    index=["Submission_Date"],
    values=['Flair'],
    columns=['Flair1'],
    aggfunc='count',
    fill_value=0

)
res = pandas.DataFrame(res.to_records())
res.columns = [col.replace("('Flair', ", '').replace(")", '') for col in res.columns]
res['Total'] = res.astype({col:float for col in res.columns if col != "Submission_Date"}).sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1) # find Total
res[[col for col in res.columns if col != "Submission_Date"]] = res[[col for col in res.columns if col != "Submission_Date"]].div(res.Total, axis=0) # divide by Total
res = res.drop(columns=['Total']) # drop Total
print(res)
```

[image]